# Issue in running code using JasperReports API on different machines 

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I created a Java project which will use *JasperReports API*. I have tested this inside and outside *NetBeans* (same machine) and it works fine. But when I try to run it on another machine the report wont load.

My code is:

```java
package reportmonitory;

import java.sql.*;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.swing.JRViewer;
import javax.swing.*;

public class monthlyreport extends JFrame {

    Connection con;
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;

    void showReport() {
        try {
            String host = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.10.11/rmcdb";
            String uName = "root";
            String uPass = "";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
            stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            String reportName = "reports/finalreport.jasper";
            java.io.InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(reportName);
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(is, null, con);
            JRViewer viewer = new JRViewer(print);
            viewer.setOpaque(true);
            viewer.setVisible(true);
            this.add(viewer);
            this.setSize(1000, 1000);
            this.setVisible(true);
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("CAUSE: " + ex.getCause());
            System.out.println("MESSAGE" + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("LOCAL MESSAGE" + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new monthlyreport().showReport();
    }
}
```

Comment: do you get any exception? and in which line of code is it thrown?

Comment: Depending on the exception shown (which you didn't include in your question), it might be the lack of a mysql driver, a network problem in the other machine which keeps it from connecting to DB, permissions in DB to connect from the other machine,...).

Comment: Thanks but all the other functions of my jar file work in the other machines,for example, posting data to the database and retrieving it.It is only the ireport that is not working.When the jar file is run in another machine,i will log in very smoothly but when it comes to viewing my ireports nothing runs

Comment: C:\Users\Aboud>java -jar ReportMonitory.jar
CAUSE: null
MESSAGEByte data not found at : C:\Users\mwaluda\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Repo
rtMonitory\src\reportmonitory\images\npa logo.jpg
LOCAL MESSAGEByte data not found at : C:\Users\mwaluda\Documents\NetBeansProject
s\ReportMonitory\src\reportmonitory\images\npa logo.jpg
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Byte data not found at : C:\Users\mwalu
da\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ReportMonitory\src\reportmonitory\images\npa logo.
jpg
        at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getBytesFromLocation(Reposit
oryUtil.java:324)

Comment: the above error is the error i get on the command prompt of the other machine when i run the ireports

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions / things to look into:

- Port forwarding for databases behind firewalls
- Specify port in case the database's connection port has been changed
- Make sure 'reports/finalreport.jasper' exists
- Packaging (due to project moving around)
- Ensure all .jar's / JasperReport API files are there
- All other files this project calls are there
- Network problem / not finding hostname: 192.168.10.11

EDIT:

The error comes from being unable to find 'npa logo.jpg'. Make sure it exists on the correct path. I notice you are looking for it on 'C:\Users\mwaluda' and you are running JaspterReports on C:\Users\Aboud. If this is a different machine, would that path still be valid?

Comment: I have checked all that, as i said all the other functions of my program are working, for example, posting data to database and retrieving it but when i try to view my ireports nothing runs

Comment: @chalasa from your error, it looks like this file is missing - C:\Users\mwaluda\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Repo rtMonitory\src\reportmonitory\images\npa logo.jpg